# kafka-configs.sh + what is the configuration after retention.ms deletion on topic

Tags: apache-kafka

On the following kafka topic syntax

```
kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides
```

we get :

```
Topic: __consumer_offsets       PartitionCount: 50      ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,min.insync.replicas=3,segment.bytes=104857600,retention.ms=7200000
```

We can see that `retention.ms=18000000`   ( its means that retention in mili second is 5 hours )

now we removed the `retention.ms` configuration by the following kafka cli

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name __consumer_offsets       --delete-config retention.ms
```

and therefore we get

```
kafka-topics.sh  --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --describe --topics-with-overrides

Topic: __consumer_offsets       PartitionCount: 50      ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: compression.type=producer,cleanup.policy=compact,min.insync.replicas=3,segment.bytes=104857600
```

As we can see above `retention.ms` was removed

Now my Question is

1. After we removed the `retention.ms` , what should be the new retention ?  , is it means that kafka is looking now on kafka configuration file as - `server.properties` ?
2. Second , what is the risks when we perform the kafka cli - `kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --alter --entity-type topics --entity-name __consumer_offsets       --delete-config` `retention.ms`

Comment: _We can see that retention.ms=18000000_, ... no? I see `7200000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All topics have a retention, so there is no risk of removing the topic-override.

If the override is removed, then yes, it'll take the default, global retention from the broker `server.properties`

Note that you may see different values if you use `--describe --bootstrap-servers kafka:9092`

Comment: sorry it was typo mistake , but your post is answered on my question , as you know I was not so sure that deletion of retention in ms , also maybe delete topics partition data or something like this  ( + 1 )

Comment: Just one note please - when I remove the retention in ms , is it necessary to restart the Kafka broker in order to take the default retention hours ?

Comment: Consumer offsets is a compact topic, so you wouldn't lose everything. I don't think you need to restart the broker with any dynamic configs like retention